# digiKam 4.14.0 cannot download photos from my PTP camera in Kubuntu 16.10

Tags: digikam, gphoto2

Ubuntu 16.10/Kubuntu 16.10 ship with the photo management program digiKam 4.14.0.

digiKam 4.14.0 can detect my PTP camera (Canon Powershot G1 X); the camera is listed under "Import -> Cameras -> xyz". When I click on my camera name nothing happens. When I run digiKam from a console I can see the error message `Failed to detect camera with GPhoto2 from Solid information`.

digiKam 4.12.0 (shipped with Kubuntu 16.04 LTS) used to open a new window with previews of the pictures stored on my camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason digiKam for Kubuntu 16.10 was built without the library `libgphoto2` and because of that PTP cameras are not supported.

Until digiKam supports PTP cameras again [gtkam](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/gtkam) can be used instead.

A way to check if PTP cameras are supported by the build of digiKam you are using is to check the shared object dependencies of the `digikam` binary with this command:

```
ldd /usr/bin/digikam | grep gph
```

The `digikam` binary inside [digikam_4.12.0-0ubuntu7_amd64.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/digikam/download) has the following matches:

```
$ ldd digikam | grep gph
    libgphoto2_port.so.12 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2_port.so.12 (0x00007fadff8dd000)
    libgphoto2.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgphoto2.so.6 (0x00007fadff658000)
```

The `digikam` binary inside [digikam_4.14.0-4ubuntu6_amd64.deb](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/digikam/download) has no matches:

```
$ ldd digikam | grep gph
$
```

[A bug report is available on Launchpad.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/digikam/+bug/1638367)